# Targeting stacked background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stacking 3 images onto a div's background.
Wondering if it's possible to target each image separately? Aka, change the opacity of individual backgrounds on the fly, either via css or javascript. I know how to change the opacity as a whole, just not sure how to target them one by one individually.

My background image css looks something like this,

```
background-image: url(https://example.com/base.jpg), url(https://example.com/overlay1.png), url(https://example.com/overlay2.png);
```

Comment: Opacity always applies to the entire element (including its content, text, background, etc), you can't change opacity to background images alone. The only exception are background colors, because you can set it as a rgba color.

Comment: ::before - background image one, div itself - background image two, ::after - background image three

Comment: As @CarolMcKay pointed out, you should do this with pseudo elements, which will allow you to change the opacity of each and every image. Just set the main container to a position of 'relative' and give it an overflow: hidden so they can appear as background images.

Comment: Thanks all for your help! Pseudo-elements worked perfectly!